# Как правильно говорить: "один за другим" или "один за одним", "не все они" или "не все из них"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

*один за другим* или *один за одним*?

Сейчас журналисты и весьма уважаемые телеведущие часто говорят *все из них* - это что, уже языковая норма?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Один за другим" правильно. "Все из них" - грубая стилистичекая ошибка, проистекающая из переводов с английского, за которые берутся люди, не умеющие переводить ('all of them' в английском соответствует русскому "все они"). Первое неправильное выражение тоже может происходить из буквальных переводов по словам (в английском русскому "один за другим" соответствует 'one by one').

Answer (score 3):

Один за одним - нарушение лексической нормы. Вот, например, в справочнике список просторечных выражений:

http://window.edu.ru/library/pdf2txt/005/41005/18310/page7

Просторечные сочетания:

```
   (Я) без понятия = не знаю / не в курсе дела
   (Мне) без разницы = все равно/безразлично
   Сколько много = так много
   Сколько время = сколько времени
   Две большие разницы = большая разница / совершенно разные вещи
   Растет над собой = повышает свой образовательный уровень / работает над собой
   Играет значение = имеет значение / играет роль
   Один за одним =один за другим
```

Все из них - тоже нарушение нормы, потому что у предлога ИЗ выделительная функция, а в этом случае ничего выделять не нужно, берётся весь объём, значит, "все они", а вот в Нацкорпусе всё верно, потому что там "не все из них" - выделяется что-то.

Answer (score 1):

> *Один за одним...*

...по-моему, не всеми лингвистами считается нарушением лексической нормы.

**Есть у Ефремовой,** хоть и с пометой *"разг."* :

> **оди́н за одни́м**
> *нареч. качеств.-обстоят. разг.*
>
> 1. Друг за другом; один за другим.
> 2. Употребляется как несогласованное определение.
>
> *Толковый словарь Ефремовой. Т. Ф.
> Ефремова. 2000.*
>
> http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/201752/%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD

**Есть и в РОС** -- без всяких ограничительных помет. См. http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%EE%E4%E8%ED+%E7%E0+%EE%E4%ED%E8%EC

**Гм… И даже в школьном словаре "Слитно-раздельно"** присутствует: https://books.google.ru/books?id=WabOAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA303&dq=%22%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD+%D0%B7%D0%B0+%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%22+%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C&hl=ru&sa=X&ei=WmfGVL-hGePmywOt2oKwCg&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%20%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%22%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C&f=false

Comment: Какой ужас!!!

Answer (score 0):

В Нацкорпусе  эти выражения встречаются часто:

1)Оказывается, не все из них знают, что... (К. И. Чуковский). Я написал много книг и далеко не все из них люблю (И. Г. Эренбург). Ведь далеко не все из них способны нацарапать свое имя на пергамене (А. П. Ладинский). Но не все из них нужны и полезны нам; многие вредны. (К. С. Станиславский).

2) А Пугачев, будто сраженный пулей, мигом упал в кусты: на том берегу, один за одним выросли шестеро конных казаков (В. Я. Шишков). И вдруг за ним ― невесть откуда, один за одним ― стали появляться люди (Василий Шукшин).

Comment: Шишков и Шукшин намеренно используют разговорные и просторечные варианты - это передача народного восприятия.

Comment: Спасибо! Но Чуковский...Эренбург... Не лучше ли сказать " все они"? Ведь по смыслу получается " все из всех"